# storing UUID in mysql database table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, uuid

I am facing a peculiar problem while storing UUID to mysql table.
I have a table with a column declaration :

```
    expenseUUID varchar(32) primary key ,
```

in this column I wish to save UUID. I have generated UUID as follows:

```
  String expenseUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  expenseUUID.replaceAll("-", "");
```

But when I try to insert expenseUUID using JDBC , I get an error saying :

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'expenseUUID'
```

What should I do resolve this issue? I am stuck. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: expenseUUID varchar(32) primary key ,

Comment: did you check the length of `expenseUUID` ?

Comment: yes , it is 32 characters long

Comment: try to set it to varchar(64) and see after inserting if it's really 32 characters long

Comment: yes okay... i will try the same

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are removing "-" from UUID string? It is no longer 70s to try to save extra 4 bytes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just missed to reassign your `replaceAll` result to `expenseUUID` var. Then your var still contains a 36 chars string.

Current :

```
String expenseUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
expenseUUID.replaceAll("-", "");
System.out.print(expenseUUID); // 9e73f8a4-dfde-438e-9eec-ac4e94817b6b
```

Corrected :

```
String expenseUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
expenseUUID = expenseUUID.replaceAll("-", "");
System.out.print(expenseUUID); // 0757c2666e934e2eb303df68bb3c9761
```

Comment: IMHO that is why OP was doing `expenseUUID.replaceAll("-", "");`

Comment: @Andreas Right, I totally missed it. Anyway, the `replaceAll` wasn't totally right.

Comment: Right :) The missing assignment of the result was what **I** completely missed, I tested the code in general but intuitively **did** assign the result in my test case ...